# Removing a member from a board and inviting them back

Tags: trello

How do I re-invite someone to a board that I had previously invited them to, and then removed them?

When I try it says they have already been invited so I can't send another invite.

Answer (score 1):

Check under the 'Pending Invitations' section of the 'Add Members...' dialog. Is there already an invitation pending for this person? If so, you can delete it and re-invite them. If not, then you have found a bug! Please email **support@trello.com** with the board URL and we will fix it.